# Filter object with another object

Tags: reactjs, object, filter

I was hoping to get some help regarding some filtering in React I'm struggeling with.

I have 2 objects, an object with recipes which I want to filter and an object (`filterIds`) with all my ID's I want to filter the recipe object with. Each recipe contains a json string (`ingredients`) which I have to parse first, work in progress... After that I want to check if my recipe at least has the same ingredients as my `filtersIds` object.

I'm currently using `every` which returns true if every ingredient is in my `filtersIds` object. But is also returns false when more ingredients are in my recipe than there are in my `filtersIds` object. Below is my code:

```
let filterIds = this.state.selectedIngredients.map(a => parseFloat(a.id));

const filteredArray = this.state.recipes.filter(recipe => {
    let ingredients = JSON.parse(recipe.ingredients).map(a => parseFloat(a.id));
    return (ingredients.every(ingredient => filterIds.indexOf(ingredient) >= 0));
});
```

The code works, it only returns my recipe when I filter on the exact ingredients of the recipe. What I want is to check if a recipe at least has all the in the `filterIds`, not the exact same values and amount. Basically my filter function should narrow down the users' search.

Comment: Please include a sample of the `selectedIngredients` and `recipes ` collections to help users assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently checking if all the elements of `ingredients` array are included in the `filterIds` array. But what you need is to check if all the elements of `filterIds` array are included in the `ingredients` array.

```
return (filterIds.every(filterId => ingredients.indexOf(filterId) >= 0));
```